# Async Function in loop - make variable available in inner function

Tags: javascript, loops, promise

I am trying do an asynchronous call in a loop, use the returned result and also make the variable 'q' available to the inner function.

How would I make q available to to the inner function (with the same value as it was before async call)?

```
var oController = this;
for (var q = 0; q < dataArray.length; q++) {
  var InspectionNo = dataArray[q].inspectionNo;

  //async call
  oController._validateInspection(InspectionNo)

    //returns flag
    .then(function(flag) {
      debugger;
      if (flag) {
        //q is not defined here
        oController._doSomething(q)
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: `q` *will* be defined, and its value will be `dataArray.length`.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for your reply, I probably need to rephrase - I was looking for q at the time of calling the async call

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var`

Comment: @neeko  replacing this function(flag){ with (flag) => { might solve the issue.

Comment: @FahadNisar arrow functions retain the `this` context but not the variable in the loop. Replacing `var` with `let` is the way to go here, as mentioned by @Erazihel.

Comment: @FrankModica got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
var oController = this;
for (var q = 0; q < dataArray.length; q++) {
            var InspectionNo = dataArray[q].inspectionNo;

            //async call
            Promise.all([oController._validateInspection(InspectionNo), q])

            //returns flag
            .then(function([flag, q]){
                    if(flag){
                        //q is not defined here
                        oController._doSomething(q)
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!